# app engine python receive mail python

Tags: google-app-engine

im trying receive email using appengine and i am trying to implement the tutorial code from the app engine docs.

everything seems to work fine, getting a 200 code every time in my live app as well as the development server but im not getting a sender or body in the logs.

sorry if its something blindingly obvious, but im completely stuck

```
 import logging
import webapp2
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.mail_handlers import InboundMailHandler


class LogSenderHandler(InboundMailHandler):
def recieve(self, mail_message):
    logging.info("Recieved a message from: " + mail_message.sender)
    bodies = mail_message.bodies('text/plain')
    logging.info(bodies)


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([LogSenderHandler.mapping()], debug=True)


- url: /_ah/mail/support@myappname.appspotmail.com
script: handle_incoming_email.app
login: admin 

inbound_services:
- mail

2013-04-13 14:12:10.556 /_ah/mail/support@myappname.appspotmail.com  200 670ms 0kb
0.1.0.20 - - [13/Apr/2013:14:12:10 -0700] "POST   /_ah/mail/support@myappname.appspotmail.com HTTP/1.1" 200 84 - -
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems because the function you need to override is receive, not recieve